# Запись в сущствующую таблицу excel данных с помощью openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

нужна помощь в записи данных в существующюю таблицу excel с помощью openpyxl. Есть таблица где есть имена, дата рождения и возраст, и в другой таблице номера телефона. Нужно записать номера телефона в первую таблицу.[image: Вот задача, что от куда и куда нудно вставить]
Есть начало кода, я понял как прочитать эти номера телефона, но не могу понять как их записать  в столбец D в книге person.xlsx. Что нужно записать в цикле?

```
from openpyxl import *                      
persons = load_workbook('persons.xlsx')     
phones = load_workbook('phones.xlsx')       
sheet_person = persons['Лист1']             
sheet_phones = phones['Лист1']              
row = sheet_phones['A']                     
for i in range(1, len(row)):
```

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#simple-usage

Comment: @Jack_oS стараюсь сделать как написанно в документации, но у меня выскакивает ValueError. ValueError: Cannot convert <Cell 'Лист1'.A1> to Excel. Как тут решить?

Comment: @Jack_oS вот мой код:

Comment: @Jack_oS 
from openpyxl import *
persons = load_workbook('persons.xlsx')
phones = load_workbook('phones.xlsx')
sheet_person = persons['Лист1']
sheet_phones = phones['Лист1']
maxrow = sheet_phones.max_row
for row in range(1, maxrow+1):
    _ = sheet_person.cell(row=row, column=4, value = sheet_phones.cell(row,1))

Comment: @Jack_oS я уже понял, я пытался взять клетку, а не значения из него, глупый я еще, ахах) Спасибо за документацию, помого)